# Users gets intermittent access denied?

Tags: 2010, permissions, user-profile, groups

I have users in domain groups, which we set permission on. Some users get access denied to certain content some of the time, but not all of the time. It's very hard to search for errors in this case. So I'm thinking of adding SharePoint groups, set permissions on these groups and add domain groups in these Sharepoint groups and hope that this will solve the problem.

But I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Am I on the right or wrong track here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at permissions on all the resource files that your page uses.  Master page catalog, style permissions, images, and stuff like that.

I think I saw this exact behavior when someone deleted Style Resource Readers group from a site collection.  Users would get access denied until a site owner logged in. When the owner logged in, the CSS would get cached somehow, and then member access worked fine until the process reset in the middle of the night. Solution was to repair member access to the style library. Longer term solution was to not delete the Style Resource Readers group.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try later today. Any idea on domain groups in sharepoint groups?

Comment: Bob is right, often it's resources. You can also use Fiddler to track down which resource is causing the 401. Changing the groups from AD to SharePoint should not make a difference.